# Performance Review - Employee Comments Section

Tags: performance-reviews

It's my first performance review (thankfully it's quite positive), and I'm not entirely sure what is appropriate for the employee comments section. Is it typically a place to comment on the job in general, or on the review itself? I have a feeling that might be specific to my workplace/review, so more generally, **what types of comments would be considered constructive and why?**

Most of the information I found via search is individuals looking for editing help on their own comments or from the management perspective. Even the management side of this seems to focus on things that would be discussed more productively in a face to face or simply lists it as 'Very Important!'.

Comment: p.s. I plan on asking my boss/coworkers how things are done around here, but I'm also interested in the general answer.

Comment: Is this a self-evaluation or the review filled out by your boss?

Comment: Formal review filled out by my boss, I had a much less formal self eval(basically just an email) earlier.

Comment: Generally I use those to comment on other staff members or aspects of the job that I personally enjoyed.  They could be used to either highlight some accomplishment that one felt was undervalued in the review, or to possibly dispute an item one felt attributed unjustly.

Comment: Brown nose your boss, if you criticise your boss you will no doubt be asked by your boss why you did so and it will only end up in an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the specific format of the particular review.  It could be any one of...

- an opportunity to provide comments about another employee, as part of feedback that goes into their review.  On such a case, provide your impression of the other employee and an example for each thing you claimed.
- an opportunity to describe the work you did, so that that description can be included in the review. In such a case, describe the work that you did. Attempt to word it so that it sounds accurate, really good, and your manager can use the verbiage as copy/paste in your review
- an opportunity to respond to the review. where I've seen this it has been for disagreement, especially if the review must be electronically accepted before you can get in front of HR.
- it could be an opportunity to provide general feedback on the review process or on the review (not just disagreement).

The only way to know is to ask your manager or read the actual document or help info your company provides.

Answer (score 0):

I was hired at a site to write Visual Basic using an Oracle database.  Over time I was asked to fix problems with various Microsoft Access databases, plan a project, teach someone how to normalize tables, etc. In such a circumstance I would have mentioned these in 'Employee Comments', so that they could check if they weren't aware these things had been done.  I also brought peace to a couple of warring factions in the building, but writing something like that down might remind people of the fight, and start it up again.